# Silent Print in angular js

Tags: javascript, java, angularjs, jakarta-ee, printing

Had used below print directive in anular js to print a document.

```
(function (angular) {
    'use strict';

    function printDirective() {
        var printSection = document.getElementById('printSection');

        // if there is no printing section, create one
        if (!printSection) {
            printSection = document.createElement('div');
            printSection.id = 'printSection';
            document.body.appendChild(printSection);
        }

        function link(scope, element, attrs) {
            element.on('click', function () {
                var elemToPrint = document.getElementById(attrs.printElementId);
                if (elemToPrint) {
                    printElement(elemToPrint);
                    //window.print();
                }
            });

            window.onafterprint = function () {
                printSection.innerHTML = '';
            }
        }

        function printElement(elem) {
            // clones the element you want to print
            var domClone = elem.cloneNode(true);
            printSection.innerHTML = '';
            printSection.appendChild(domClone);
            window.print();
        }

        return {
            link: link,
            restrict: 'A'
        };
    }

    angular.module('app').directive('ngPrint', [printDirective]);
}(window.angular));
```

This will prompt a modal box to select print and other print configuration.

```
<button class="btn"   ng-print print-element-id="printThisElement"><i class="fa fa-print"></i> Print</button>
```

Now, I need to remove the modal box and to do a silent print, where we can set which printer and how many prints and other print configuration can be set through the angular js code and it should work in all the browsers.

Can we add any machine settings on the client machine so that we can achieve silent printing with the default printer configuration in the client system.

Comment: I don't think browser will allow that

Comment: Is there any work around to achieve this, its a web application using angular js and Java/j2ee

Comment: I don't think so. Wait for other SO users, might they have some work around.